# Getting Action Mailer + Devise to play together nicely

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I followed the guides - steps 1 - 2.1.3.

I can't get the system to send an email. This is all on my development environment.

In my Users Controller, I edited the create action to look like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The user_mailer.rb file looks like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "no-reply@mydomain.com"

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = "http://localhost.com:3000/users/login"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to MySite")
  end

end
```

My /config/initializers/devise.rb file looks like this:

```
  Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@mydomain.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating an user. By default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating an user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable = true

  # Set this to true to use Basic Auth for AJAX requests.  True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication
  # config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  config.stretches = 10

  # Define which will be the encryption algorithm. Devise also supports encryptors
  # from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1, :authlogic_sha512 (then
  # you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior) and :restful_authentication_sha1
  # (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
  config.encryptor = :bcrypt

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  config.pepper = "o27yo2oeb$2h2oiuhoiuKJH#KJ#K@JHLK@JHLKJLSKHGKJAgdskajgdkuyagdau"

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # The time you want to give your user to confirm his account. During this time
  # he will be able to access your application without confirming. Default is nil.
  # When confirm_within is zero, the user won't be able to sign in without confirming. 
  # You can use this to let your user access some features of your application 
  # without confirming the account, but blocking it after a certain period 
  # (ie 2 days). 
  # config.confirm_within = 2.days

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, a valid remember token can be re-used between multiple browsers.
  # config.remember_across_browsers = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length
  # config.password_length = 6..20

  # Regex to use to validate the email address
  # config.email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again.
  # config.timeout_in = 10.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  # config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  # config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  # config.scoped_views = true

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes.
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Configure sign_out behavior. 
  # By default sign_out is scoped (i.e. /users/sign_out affects only :user scope).
  # In case of sign_out_all_scopes set to true any logout action will sign out all active scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = false

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists. Default is [:html]
  # config.navigational_formats = [:html, :iphone]

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not (yet) supported by Devise,
  # you can configure them inside the config.warden block. The example below
  # allows you to setup OAuth, using http://github.com/roman/warden_oauth
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.oauth(:twitter) do |twitter|
  #     twitter.consumer_secret = <YOUR CONSUMER SECRET>
  #     twitter.consumer_key  = <YOUR CONSUMER KEY>
  #     twitter.options :site => 'http://twitter.com'
  #   end
  #   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :twitter_oauth
  # end
end
```

My Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_current_user

  protected 

  def set_current_user
    Authorization.current_user = current_user
  end

end
```

Output from log when I register a new user (btw, I have commented out the config_action.mailer_raise.delivery line).

```
Started GET "/users/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-03 11:53:12 -0500
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-03 11:53:58 -0500
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VPBCmkVSBXzyIXZf4Y3XUo1lHagxWXrBAfbtuO2Hi0M=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@email.com')) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "password_salt", "remember_created_at", "remember_token", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ('2010-12-03 16:53:58.280017', NULL, NULL, 'test@email.com', '$2a$10$nBvgG4dRFX2tRBtHrU9P7OTPAUjT4Zb0JhpEP4v5lzPIjOp40Lcoy', NULL, NULL, '$2a$10$nBvgG4dRFX2tRBtHrU9P7O', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2010-12-03 16:53:58.280017', NULL)
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = '2010-12-03 16:53:58.297987', "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "last_sign_in_at" = '2010-12-03 16:53:58.297987', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "sign_in_count" = 1, "updated_at" = '2010-12-03 16:53:58.298381' WHERE ("users"."id" = 4)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 224ms


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-03 11:53:58 -0500
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 4) LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "roles".id = "assignments".role_id WHERE (("assignments".user_id = 4))
  Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT * FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "projects_users" ON "projects".id = "projects_users".project_id WHERE ("projects_users".user_id = 4 )
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (74.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 226ms (Views: 81.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

When I register a new user, it creates the user and allows me to login - but I never get the email in my inbox.

Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding these lines in config/environments/development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail #:smtp
```